# Spring Boot 1.2.5.RELEASE @Transaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

After upgrading to spring boot 1.2.5 an exception is being thrown when attempting to execute the below query.

Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "insert into some_table (some_id) VALUES (?1)", nativeQuery = true)
public void insertSomeTable(long some_id);
```

It's as if the @Transactional annotation is being ignored. With spring boot 1.2.1 this works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

You're apparently using JTA 1.2's `@javax.transaction.Transactional` and the support for that is unfortunately broken in the Spring Data release that Boot release includes. The workaround is to use Spring Framework's `@org.springframework.transaction.Transactional`.

## Details

The Spring Data release included with that Spring Boot version ships a fix for a transaction bug that existed before. This effectively "fixes" the transaction handling on repositories to be controlled by Spring Data.

Unfortunately that switches of the support for JTA 1.2's `@Transactional` which you are apparently using. I've fixed [DATACMNS-732](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-732) (to bei included in Fowler SR2 and Gosling RC1) and created a [ticket in Spring Framework](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13246) to improve the scenario within the library (we basically suffered from not picking up JTA 1.2 support due to the need to copy a class).

Comment: This was indeed the problem. I was using javax.transaction.Transactional. Switching to @org.springframework.transaction.Transactional solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I had the exact same problem. Thank you so much!